# How can (false == false == true) be true

Tags: javascript, boolean

While I was programming I had an unexpected outcome in my if statement.

How in the world can this code alert true?
I didn't found anything that could help me at W3S, and really would like to know why these alerts "true"

```
window.alert(false == false == true); //alerts true
window.alert(false == (false == true));//even this alerts true
```

Comment: Because `(false == true)` == false and `false == false` equal true

Comment: [Operator Precedence.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: Does it help if I point out that you also cannot write `2 < 3 < 4`, but instead you need to write `2 < 3 && 3 < 4`?

Comment: To save you some pain in the future, you should know you don't have to keep using `window.alert` to debug stuff. In Chrome, ctrl+shift+j will open the dev console where you can evaluate javascript. In Firefox, ctrl+shift+i. Or just use [Node's REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) and don't even bother with a browser.

Comment: Also MDN is vastly preferred to W3S.

Comment: @epascarello as mentioned in my post actually the precedence does not matter here. No matter the precedence, the expression would hold true

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**First Case**

```
false == false == true
```

will be evaluated as

```
(false == false) == true
```

because [expressions are evaluated from left to right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Associativity), by default. which reduces to

```
true == true
```

since `false` is actually equal to `false`. That is why it is evaluated to `true`.

**Second Case**

```
false == (false == true)
```

is reduced to

```
false == false
```

because `false` is not equal to `true`. That is why the entire expression is `true` because `false` is equal to `false`.

Answer (score 3):

The execution will start from left hand side.

```
window.alert(false == false == true);
```

at first `false== false` is true. Then `true==true` is true.

In second case, since you have using parenthesis `()` that will be executed at first.

`false == true` is false.

Then `false == false` is true.

Answer (score 2):

Is it true that `false == true`? I think it is apparent that this is not true, thus `(false == true)` is `false` and therefor `false == (false == true)` (as we've already noticed that the second part is false).

As for the first example - actually no matter the order of evaluation it will hold true(I leave that to you as a logical exercise). Still javascript guarantees the evaluation order to be left to right thus this expression is the same as`(false == false) == true`. Again I leave to you to prove this is true.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> false == false == true
> ```

`false == false`, this is `true`, which equals `true`.

> ```
> false == (false == true)
> ```

`false == true`, this is `false`, which equals `false`.

Answer (score 0):

First line - from left to right it compares `false == false` which is `true`, then compared to `true` returns `true`

Second line - from left to right it compares `(false == true)` which is `false`, then comparison of `false` and `false` returns `true`

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct.

Case 1: `false == false == true`
this is similar to `(false == false) == true`

The evaluation is
`false == false IS true` and `true == true IS true`

Case 2: `false == (false == true)`
this is similar to `(false == true) == false`

The evaluation is
`false == true IS false` and `false == false IS true`

Hope this helps